# Confused about the way this speaker is wired

Tags: ground, speakers

From [this article](http://www.popsci.com/diy/article/2008-04/build-pocket-theremin-cheap):

[image]

I don't understand why one end of the speaker is connected to the + of the battery.  If the output of the 555 goes into one end of the speaker, shouldn't the other end of the speaker go to ground?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output pin (3) of a 555 is a push-pull (totempole) output, which means that it can both sink and source current. Hence you can connect the speaker either way, to ground or to power.

Not that this is a very elegant circuit, a 5k pot in series with an 8 Ohm speaker, juk!

Comment: Ahh ok, so it wouldn't make a difference and was probably just a design choice then.

Comment: Actually, 5K isn't so bad. The 555 output saturates at about 200 mA (IIRC), so this gives you about a 200:1 range in current through the speaker, or a 46dB change in volume.

Comment: That 200 mA is a recommended operating condition, not a guaranteed saturation! And to give a reasonable 'feel' the potmeter should be (anti?) log.